# How to re-position tooltip to top left or on mouse over in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to change the place where the tooltip is displayed in the JSF. Like to top left or Top right or Mouse over.

```
 <p:tooltip for="rowEditButton" value="Click to Edit" ></p:tooltip>
```

Mouse over is what i am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use primefaces-extension tooltip. It has everything what you need.
[Primefaces extension - tooltip demo](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-myfaces/views/tooltip.jsf)

Comment: have been using the primeface all the way. Don't want to add prime-face extentions just for this.